# What to do if the learning curve of a loss does not show down trend?

Tags: deep-learning

I trained a neural network for 2000 steps, each corresponding to an upgrade in the params, and it takes 9000 steps to get through the whole training set. However, the loss curve didn't show down trend but juggle around a small range, except a drop at the beginning of the first epoch. Should I stop and make some changes, or should I keep training and when should I stop if the curve does not show down trend? I use google colab and pay with my own money, I have to take into account the cost, and cannot risk my money to keep training without certainty. I am looking for a general advice, and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

1/4 epoch is not long, but if it lasts for 1-4 epochs, it's usually a sign of a wrong learning rate, either too high or too low. Another problem could be that your data is not scaled, if the variables are on different scales the NN converges much harder, so I would suggest:

1. Check your data, are your variables/features scaled?
2. Re-train with a higher and/or lower learning rate
3. The loss should decrease fairly quickly within the first two epochs (so 18000 steps), if not, go back to step 2.

To get a feeling for your model and the training, you would benefit from a 'baseline' loss, so the minimum loss your model should easily outperform, this could be for example the loss for an intercept only model. If you are unable to decrease your loss below that baseline, something is seriously wrong with your hyperparameters such as the learning rate (e.g. see https://citoverse.github.io/cito/articles/B-Training_neural_networks.html)

Comment: I'd start with a low learning rate (1e-6) and then go from there.